# How to push notification to a console application using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, console-application

Code below gets status and file from DB which is basically a pull mechanism, since it breaks loop only if the status is changed to completed but, I have a problem here. It should fail in some error codes and keep going in case of some error codes.

```
while (KeepRunning)
{
    try
    {
        if (!finder.GetFile(processID, out file))
        {
            KeepRunning = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message: {0}", ex.Message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

I think, I need opposite direction call. Instead keeping loop on until the status changes, I want to keep client app to wait on the notification from server, this way I can over come the problem with error code.

In sort, instead of pull mechanism, I need push mechanism.

How can this be done? Does anybody know good reference to implement pushing from server to client?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you know...

Comment: This files are very small and stored in database. Would FileSystemWatcher works for this case?

Comment: `finder` is a database context?

Comment: finder is a class calls into web api which ultimately calls into DB.

Comment: Well, dbs can't do push notifications. You're next best bet is do single your call out to a "last updated" column and check for a delta. This is usually how cache-busters work for when to pull new entities.

Comment: I think servicebus notification class can do this, but couldn't find any reference on how to implement.

Comment: If you have access to the server, you can have a console app or windows service repeatedly poll the database, then send a notification via SignalR to your client app when it detects a new file in the database. If you can save the file in a folder instead of a database, you could make the console app/windows service use FileSystemWatcher to watch the folder for new files instead.